# Heroku remote debugging Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, remote-debugging, rubymine

I'm trying to set up remote debugging for a Rails app running on Heroku. I'm trying to use RubyMine, but I'm fine with a non-RubyMine solution as well.

#### What I've tried

- The Heroku integration for RubyMine uses a deprecated version of the Heroku API, so it won't help.
- I tried running the command suggested in the [Heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/exec#remote-debugging), and it seems to work:

I run `$ heroku ps:forward 9090`, and the output is:

```
Establishing credentials... done
SOCKSv5 proxy server started on port 1080
Listening on 9090 and forwarding to web.1:9090
Use CTRL+C to stop port fowarding
```

Then in the RubyMine IDE it says it's Connected, but it doesn't display any logs or respond to breakpoints, only giving me this error message:

> Limited Debugging Info: Please select relevant remote Ruby SDK for full debugging info

"Select" is a link, but all it only provides the options of Ruby versions, and I have the correct version selected.

- I tried using the *Ruby remote debug* option in RubyMine, as suggested in the [RubyMine docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/remote-debugging.html).

I ran `$ heroku run rdebug-ide --host 0.0.0.0 --port 9090 --dispatcher-port 2525 -- $COMMAND$` on the remote server, and that works:

```
Fast Debugger (ruby-debug-ide 0.7.0.beta4, debase 0.2.2, file filtering is supported) listens on 0.0.0.0:2525
```

But then I get a timeout error:

[image]

## What else can I try? Or how can I fix any of these?

Comment: What do you mean by remote debugging ? what actual actions do you require on your app at Heroku?